# How to upload a file to Azure storage?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-storage

My question is simple. How to upload a file to Azure storage?

Thank you.

Comment: What you want to upload to ? Azure Blob or Azure File?

Comment: @George Chen, I want to upload a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is my test to upload a file to root directory, it uses **Azure Storage SDK v8**, if you want to use the latest version sdk, you could use this Azure File SDK:[Azure File client library for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file). It will show you how to use the SDK and it also includes many samples, and this is the [upload sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/164cf2f4c6bb88c18f0fd45ff0e7cd7d2ee50c1c/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file/src/samples/java/com/azure/storage/file/FileSample.java#L88).

```
final String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
                    "AccountName=your storage account name;" +
                    "AccountKey=your storage connection key";
    try {
        // Use the CloudStorageAccount object to connect to your storage account
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the file client.
        CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

        // Get a reference to the file share
        CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("windows");

        //Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

        // Define the path to a local file.
        final String filePath = "C:\\Users\\georgec\\Documents\\test.json";

        //Get a reference to the file you want to upload
        CloudFile cloudFile = rootDir.getFileReference("test.json");
        cloudFile.uploadFromFile(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great, but now I have a problem with the download. I get the URL, add the SAS token and I do not get a download link, but I get the content of the file. For example, I uploaded a .rtf file and I get this when I try to download:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf600
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0....

Comment: The file's contents will be either displayed inline in the browser or the user will be prompted to download the file,Depending on the file's content type. Like the txt or json it will display, so maybe you could download it with code or with powershell and you could also the [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#download-a-file) to do it.

Comment: If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: yes you are right. In case I add a doc file or zip it gets downloaded. Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you ever had problems with uploading larger files. I can not upload files larger than 2 MB. No error is shown, it just does not work.